# grails findByDomain returns null

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-one

A domain `Staff` has a `User`.

```
class Person {
      User user
}

class Staff extends Person {
      //other properties
}

class User {
      String username
      String password
}
```

I know a user logged in, now I want to find the `Staff` by the same logged in `User`. No relation is maintained from `User`'s side.

The code I am implementing is :

```
def createdBy = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
log.info("User id : "+createdBy.id) // it works
def staff = Staff.findByUser(createdBy) //it returns null
```

**Is this not applicable in GORM or I'm missing something?**

[grails findBy documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/findBy.html) has nothing to tell about findByDomain().

Comment: Have you tried `Person.findByUser(createdBy)`? I am not sure whether you would be able to get Staff from User if there is no direct relation.

Comment: What you have should work. Similar to @dmahapatro is saying, is possible you saved the child to a Person vs a Staff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is **CLOSED** as the **error** was while inserting a `Staff` with a `User` which was not heppening in proper way.(poor `grails` didn't notify me.)

Above code works perfectly.

```
def createdBy = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
def staff     = Staff.findByUser(createdBy)
```

But, meanwhile implemented another way of finding `Staff` in criteria way :

```
    def createdBy = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
    def staff     = staffCriteria.get{
        user{
            idEq(createdBy.id)
        }
    }
```

Comment: @danielad He figured it out himself after trying, the question was posted before the answer. Duh

Comment: @WaqasShah SO only has room for constructive answers / criticism. Consider this a warning.